# Unable to open port on debian vps

Tags: linux, networking, debian, firewall, iptables

Trying to open 51820 UDP
I do

`iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT`

then `iptables -L`

I can see

```
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:51820
```

then I do
`/sbin/iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4` and
`/sbin/iptables-save` and `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

now if I do `nmap –sT –p-65535 localhost` I don't see 51820

If I do `ss -lntp` I don't see 51820

If I check for open port with port checker website it says closed too

my process is running

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS          PORTS                                                                      NAMES
626a571479e7   linuxserver/wireguard:latest   "/init"                  About an hour ago   Up 9 minutes    0.0.0.0:51820->51820/udp, :::51820->51820/udp                              wireguard
```

this is my docker compose if any help

```
services:
  wireguard:
    image: linuxserver/wireguard:latest
    container_name: wireguard
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
    ports:
      - "51820:51820/udp"
```

and in my config I have

```
[Interface]
ListenPort = 51820
```

Comment: You opened an UDP port and your `lsof` command list network files with **TCP** state `LISTEN`. Try with this command : `lsof -nP -iUDP -sUDP:LISTEN` - Second point, `iptable` manage kernel firewall rules (and routing), there is no link with the process that listens on port `51820`. To check listened ports on your machine : `ss -lntp`

Comment: @hidigoudi thank you for your insight. I updated the question with your suggestions. `lsof -nP -iUDP -sUDP:LISTEN` does not work so I used `nmap` and also `ss -lntp` but still same problem; looks like the port is closed

Comment: You should replace a tag with Docker among your tags. Docker routes and uses NAT. It won't use a local socket (unless `docker-proxy` is enabled).

Comment: @A.B sorry but I am confused at what you are asking

Comment: Running Debian is not that important. Having a Docker context is more important. To insist that no socket is to be expected on the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nmap` command does not scan `UDP` ports by default. You need to use this option : `-sU`. If `nmap` does not find port `51820` opened, it means that no process is listenning on this port (on `localhost`).

The command should be :

```
nmap –sU –p 51820 localhost
```

To allow a connection and port scan from external, what you are calling "portchecker website", you need to create a NAT on port `51820` in your router to the machine that runs the `Wireguard`. Also, you must be sure that you "portchecker website" can scan `UDP` ports.

In my opinion, the port `51820` is opened on your container, **not on the host machine**. The container should have an IP address (different from the host IP address). If you run the `nmap` on the container's IP instead of host IP, you should see your opened port.

Here the command to check the IP of your docker container :

```
docker container inspect wireguard
```

### Update

After a detailed discussion with @jotyhista, it appears that the issue comes from the Docker image itself. The `Wireguard` service is stopped and nothing is listening on port `51820`. The command `wg` returns nothing. It's for this reason the `nmap` command shows the port `closed`.

A deeper investigation into why the `Wireguard` service is down needs to be conduct (check in logs? Bad configuration?). This will fix the initial issue and the port will be `open`.

Comment: it does not show anything. I have a docker wireguard open on this port

Comment: If it shows nothing, it means that the machine you ran the `nmap` is not listenning on this port. I can't help you more without other information. - Maybe `Wireguard` runs on the Docker container ? If so, you should have an IP address for this container.

Comment: If I use a portchecker website it says the port is closed. even if no process is running it should show an open port

Comment: That's incorrect, if no process is running, the port is closed. It's the same for all services that use sockets and network. If `apache2` service is stopped, all web ports are closed. Same for `postfix` etc... - The `nmap` should return something like :
`PORT      STATE  SERVICE
51820/udp closed unknown` - Check if the service is running correctly.

Comment: I edited my answer for more precision.

Comment: I posted the running process in my question; it is running and configured correctly as far as I can tell

Comment: Thanks, answer edited. If you still have issue, we will continue in chat.

Comment: thanks for that. Looks like the issue is with docker then since I did `nmap -sU -p 51820 172.31.0.2` from the docker host and got nothing. weird; my container is running and shows listening on the port

Comment: *from the docker host* ? If you are in the docker host, you should use `localhost` instead of the `172.31.0.2`. `172.31.0.2` is the host machine or the docker host ?

Comment: docker host is my VPS. `172.31.0.2` was the docker container ip as shown by `inspect`. I did the same command with localhost and found an open port on 51820

Comment: Ok great, so it works! The machine listening on port 51820 is `172.31.0.2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150581/discussion-between-jotyhista-and-hidigoudi).